# Why did Buddha continue jhāna after enlightenment?

Tags: nirvana, jhana, stages

Can you tell me why Buddha used to go in different levels of absorption/ jhāna/musing even after nirvana for reference Mahā Parinibbāna Sutta  (DN 16) and An 3.63 venaga sutta?

Comment: Sounds like a good question. Welcome.

Comment: Why not? For the enlightened noble ones, attaining the jhana state in meditation is easy. There's nothing wrong with having a good time when it hurts nobody.

Answer (score 1):

All states of consciousness are impermanent, i.e. they arise , change and vanish. It is possible to come out of cessation of feelings and perceptions and re-enter it through meditation. Buddha deferred his final extinguishment so that he could teach his disciples and establish sangha. Nibbana is nirodh meaning prevention of ignorance, cravings , hatred or delusions. A fully extinguishedk being doesn’t give rise to body , feelings , perceptions, choices or consciousness because all the cravings are gone.

Comment: source for the part "he deferred his final extinguishment.." ?

Answer (score 0):

The Buddhas can enter the jhanas whenever they want.

There is no specific reason why they must or must not do it.

They don't do it to run away from pain, because that would imply that they experience aversion to pain. Aversion and repulsion is no longer found in the  liberated.

This applied to Gautama Buddha and also the Arahant disciple Kassapa, according to the sutta below.

> “Mendicants, whenever I want, quite secluded from sensual pleasures,
> secluded from unskillful qualities, I enter and remain in the first
> absorption, which has the rapture and bliss born of seclusion, while
> placing the mind and keeping it connected. And so does Kassapa.
>
> Whenever I want, as the placing of the mind and keeping it connected
> are stilled, I enter and remain in the second absorption, which has
> the rapture and bliss born of immersion, with internal clarity and
> mind at one, without placing the mind and keeping it connected. And so
> does Kassapa.
>
> Whenever I want, with the fading away of rapture, I enter and remain
> in the third absorption, where I meditate with equanimity, mindful and
> aware, personally experiencing the bliss of which the noble ones
> declare, ‘Equanimous and mindful, one meditates in bliss.’ And so does
> Kassapa.
>
> Whenever I want, with the giving up of pleasure and pain, and the
> ending of former happiness and sadness, I enter and remain in the
> fourth absorption, without pleasure or pain, with pure equanimity and
> mindfulness. And so does Kassapa.
>
> Whenever I want, going totally beyond perceptions of form, with the
> ending of perceptions of impingement, not focusing on perceptions of
> diversity, aware that ‘space is infinite’, I enter and remain in the
> dimension of infinite space. And so does Kassapa.
>
> Whenever I want, going totally beyond the dimension of infinite space,
> aware that ‘consciousness is infinite’, I enter and remain in the
> dimension of infinite consciousness. And so does Kassapa.
>
> Whenever I want, going totally beyond the dimension of infinite
> consciousness, aware that ‘there is nothing at all’, I enter and
> remain in the dimension of nothingness. And so does Kassapa.
>
> Whenever I want, going totally beyond the dimension of nothingness, I
> enter and remain in the dimension of neither perception nor
> non-perception. And so does Kassapa.
>
> Whenever I want, going totally beyond the dimension of neither
> perception nor non-perception, I enter and remain in the cessation of
> perception and feeling. And so does Kassapa.
> [SN 16.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn16.9/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

Comment: @Ruben2020 are you sure Kassapa refers to a Buddha? Or does Kassapa refer to an Arahant disciple?

Comment: @DhammaDhatu You're right. SN 16 is about the arahant disciple Kassapa.

Answer (score 0):

A Buddha has fully developed & is endowed with the Noble Eightfold Path, including jhana (right concentration). [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html) says:

> Of those, right view is the forerunner. And how is right view the forerunner? In one of right view, right resolve comes into being. In one of right resolve, right speech comes into being. In one of right speech, right action... In one of right action, right livelihood... In one of right livelihood, right effort... In one of right effort, right mindfulness... In one of right mindfulness, right concentration... In one of right concentration, right knowledge... In one of right knowledge, right release comes into being. Thus the learner is endowed with eight factors, and the arahant with ten.

Jhana has become the natural meditation of a Buddha. Whenever the physical body of a Buddha stops exerting itself, the mind quickly returns to jhana.

A Buddha does not *go into* jhana. The opposite occurs. A Buddha *emerges from* jhana to perform his worldly duties, such as eating, washing, walking & teaching.

Answer (score 0):

Dhyanas is about concentration of the mind.

1)
Buddha used these to change normal people's perspective towards Buddha by showing them what they consider as magic, special abilities.

2)
Buddha used these abilities to look at past, future, tell stories of different times,look at nature, universe, talk to Gods, Bahamas, and show them, how below they and their abilities are(compered to Buddha).

Answer (score -1):

One of my favorite suttas is MN121

> [MN121:3.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn121/en/sujato#mn121:3.3): ‘Ānanda, these days I usually practice the meditation on emptiness.’

The Buddha moved regularly about his world as a teacher engaging with villages and people, spreading the Dhamma out of compassion. It is therefore significant that MN121 starts the meditation on emptiness with this consideration:

> [MN121:4.6](https://suttacentral.net/mn121/en/sujato#mn121:4.6): ‘Here there is no stress due to the perception of village or the perception of people.
> [MN121:4.7](https://suttacentral.net/mn121/en/sujato#mn121:4.7): There is only this modicum of stress, namely the oneness dependent on the perception of wilderness.’

From this we may reason that the Buddha found such meditation on emptiness to be a necessary and healing counterpoint to the stress of the teaching journey through villages and with people. As the meditation on emptiness proceeds, stress fades away into emptiness.

Regarding other specific meditations, it simply seems reasonable for any good teacher to regularly practice what they teach. Indeed, during his last day on earth, the Buddha did just that.

Yet the Buddha did emphasize the meditation on emptiness in particular.

> [MN121:12.7](https://suttacentral.net/mn121/en/sujato#mn121:12.7): That’s how emptiness is born in them—genuine, undistorted, and pure.
> [MN121:13.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn121/en/sujato#mn121:13.1): Whatever ascetics and brahmins enter and remain in the pure, ultimate, supreme emptiness—whether in the past, future, or present—all of them enter and remain in this same pure, ultimate, supreme emptiness.
> [MN121:13.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn121/en/sujato#mn121:13.4): So, Ānanda, you should train like this: ‘We will enter and remain in the pure, ultimate, supreme emptiness.’
> [MN121:13.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn121/en/sujato#mn121:13.5): That’s how you should train.”

Notably, the Buddha also arose each day and proceeded through the world, unattached to emptiness, accepting the stress of villages and people.

Comment: Stress of villages and people? Was the Buddha taking any part in that stress? I would reason that since the Buddha had no craving an aversion, no trace of stress would arise in him..for stress is due to craving.

Comment: Lifting a weight takes effort, this is muscular stress. Likewise, villages and people are stressful in that they take effort.  Stress is different than distress.  The Buddha got sore from effort (DN33) like any other human.  Villages and people are tiring. That is the meaning of "stress" here.

Comment: So physical stress, but no distress. That would mean it’s all the same to him if he sits in jhana or if he acts in the world?